# Clojure MapReduce Reducer

Tags: clojure

This program forms the reducer of a Hadoop MapReduce job. It reads data in from stdin that is tab delimited.

```
foo    1
foo    1
bar    1
```

and outputs

```
foo    2
bar    1
```

Any suggestions for improvements?

```
(use '[clojure.string :only [split]])
(def reducer (atom {}))

(defn update-map [map key]
  (merge-with + map {key 1}))

(doseq [line (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))]
  (let [k (first (split line #"\t"))]
    (swap! reducer update-map k)))

(doseq [kv @reducer]
  (println (format "%s\t%s" (first kv) (second kv))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably a bit too late to help OP, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this question, here's a nice succinct way of doing it, using the `frequencies` function:

```
(doseq [[word freq] (frequencies
                      (map
                        #(re-find #"^[^\t]+" %) ;; just get the first non-tab characters
                        (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))))]
  (println (str word "\t" freq)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `reduce` instead of the first `doseq`? Something along the lines (untested, entered directly here):

```
(def response
  (reduce (fn [map line]
            (let [k (fist (split line #"\t"))]
               (update-map map k)))
          {} (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*)))

(doseq [kv response]
  (println (format "%s\t%s" (first kv) (second kv))))
```

Then you won't need the `atom` either.

Answer (score 0):

Can ouput contain numbers other than 1? Like:

```
foo 1
foo 3
bar 10
```

If so, then:

```
(use '[clojure.string :only [split]])

(def parsed-input
  (for [line (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))
        :let [[k v] (split line #"\t")]]
    {k (Double/parseDouble v)}))

(def table (apply (partial merge-with + {}) parsed-input))

(doseq [[k v] table]
  (println (str k "\t" v)))
```

Outputs:

```
bar     10.0
foo     4.0
```

If it's just 1's `frequencies` will do as suggested.